# Difference between k-means clustering and creating groups by brute force approach

Tags: python, r, statistics, cluster-analysis

I have a task to find similar parts based on numeric dimensions--diameters, thickness--and categorical dimensions--material, heat treatment, etc. I have a list of 1 million parts. My approach as a programmer is to put all parts on a list, pop off the first part and use it as a new "cluster" to compare the rest of the parts on the list based on the dimensions. As a part on the list matches the categorical dimensions and numerical dimensions--within 5 percent--I will add that part to the cluster and remove from the initial list. Once all parts in the list are compared with the initial cluster part's dimensions, I will pop the next part off the list and start again, populating clusters until no parts remain on the original list. This is a programmatic approach. I am not sure if this is most efficient way of categorizing parts into "clusters" or if k-means clustering would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "better".

What you do seems to be related to "leader" clustering. But that is a very primitive form of clustering that will usually not yield competitive results. But with 1 million points, your choices are limited, and kmeans does not handle categorical data well.

But until you decide what is 'better', there probably is nothing 'wrong' with your greedy approach.

An obvious optimization would be to first split all the data based on the categorical attributes (as you expect them to match exactly). That requires just one pass over the data set and a hash table. If your remaining parts are small enough, you could try kmeans (but how would you choose k), or DBSCAN (probably using the same threshold you already have) on each part.